# vb.net save textbox values for later use

Tags: vb.net, search, textbox

I use a `textbox` in my form to search for words in pdf files. I want to save these search words somewhere for later use. So when the user types a letter in the `textbox` there will be a pulldown with previous searched words. Something like windows does in Explorer.

Does anyone have an example or is someone familiar with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store and retrieve a list of search words in an application settings entry of type [`StringCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.stringcollection?view=net-5.0) as the data source of the [`TextBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox.autocompletecustomsource?view=net-5.0) property.

**Add new entry**

- Select `YourAppName` Properties from the **Project** menu.
- Select the **Settings** tab.
- Add new entry in the **Name** column, say: *SearchWords*.
- From the **Type** column, select **System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection**.
- Close the dialog and save.

**Retrieve the search words**

In the Form's constructor or `Load` event, say you have a search `TextBox` named `txtSearch`:

```vb
' +
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Collections.Specialized

Private Sub YourForm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If My.Settings.SearchWords Is Nothing Then
        My.Settings.SearchWords = New StringCollection
    End If

    Dim acc As New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    acc.AddRange(My.Settings.SearchWords.Cast(Of String).ToArray())

    txtSearch.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest
    txtSearch.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource
    txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource = acc
End Sub
```

**Update the collection**

You need to add the new words whenever you perform a search:

```vb
' When you click a search button...
Private Sub btnSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSearch.Click
    AddSearchWord()
End Sub

' If you call the search routine when you press the Enter key...
Private Sub txtSearch_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles txtSearch.KeyDown
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        AddSearchWord()
    End If
End Sub

' Update the collection...
Private Sub AddSearchWord()
    If txtSearch.Text.Trim.Length = 0 Then Return

    If Not txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Contains(txtSearch.Text) Then

        If txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count > 10 Then
            txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.RemoveAt(
                txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Count - 1)
        End If

        txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Insert(0, txtSearch.Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Save the collection**

Update the `SearchWord` string collection when you close the Form:

```vb
Private Sub YourForm_FormClosing(sender As Object, e As FormClosingEventArgs) Handles MyBase.FormClosing
    My.Settings.SearchWords = New StringCollection
    My.Settings.SearchWords.AddRange(txtSearch.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Cast(Of String).ToArray)
    My.Settings.Save()
End Sub
```

**Demo**

[image: SOQ66840517]

Comment: what is Sub New()? Is that a sub I have to call in the form load?

Comment: @Marco No, that is the Form's constructor., Wait I'll move that to the Form.Load event.

Comment: Somehow the values are not saved to the String Collection.

Comment: I tried without  debugging but the behaviour is still strange. Some words are saved, some are not. When I check Settings the StringCollection is always empty. So where are the words saved that do popup?

Comment: It seems to be working now. What I still dont understand is where the search strings are saved. The StringCollection is empty all the time

Comment: @Marco In your user profile. Like: `C:\Users\YouName\AppData\Local\YourSolution\YourApp\Version\user.config`. Make sure that you call the `AddSearchWord` to update the collection. Put break points in the mentioned events to see whether they fire. You won't see the words in the `Settings` designer. Unless you add them there.

Comment: `<ArrayOfString xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                        <string>Nucleair</string>
                        <string>RPAS</string>
                        <string>VBIED</string>
                        <string>chemical</string>
                        <string>radiological</string>
                        <string>test</string>
                        <string>nieuw</string>
                        <string>biological</string>
                        <string>me</string>
                    </ArrayOfString>`

Comment: @Marco ah, you found it. Exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I found some code [Saving text box values to a file to load again](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a8dd49f1-f7bf-4a0a-b071-c5dfd8e5e889/saving-text-box-values-to-a-file-to-load-again?forum=Vsexpressvb) that I changed to my needs. It saves the content of my ComboBox1 to a textfile when I click my Submit button. When I load the form the textfile is read and loaded into the ComboBox1 as previous used searches.

```
   'now save the search word to our textfile
    PresetName = TextBoxFreeText.Text
    If PresetName <> "" Then
        TextBoxFreeText.Items.Add(PresetName)
        Call SaveData(PresetName)
    End If
```

The code to load the saved values:

```
Private Sub ReadData()
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(FilePath) = True Then
            myReader = New StreamReader(FilePath)
            Dim myText = myReader.ReadLine
            While myText IsNot Nothing
                listPreset.Add(myText)
                myText = myReader.ReadLine
            End While
            myReader.Close()
            'Add Preset Names to ComboBox
            If listPreset.Count > 0 Then
                Dim PresetName As String
                Dim index As Integer
                For i = 0 To listPreset.Count - 1
                    index = listPreset.Item(i).IndexOf(",")
                    PresetName = Mid(listPreset.Item(i), 1, index)
                    TextBoxFreeText.Items.Add(PresetName)
                Next
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

The code to save the content of ComboBox1

```
Private Sub SaveData(ByVal PresetName As String)
        Dim FileString As String = PresetName & ","
        'Build File String

        FileString &= TextBoxFreeText.Text & ","
        listPreset.Add(FileString)
        myWriter = New StreamWriter(FilePath)
        For i = 0 To listPreset.Count - 1
            myWriter.WriteLine(listPreset.Item(i))
        Next
        myWriter.Close()

    End Sub
```

There are still two things I want to change. I will ask in a new question.

1. prevent duplicate search string to be entered in the textfile.
2. set a maximum to the search string loaded in ComboBox1 (maybe 10 words)

Comment: Use an application setting entry of type `StringCollection` to store and retrieve a list of strings for this. See [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e0608b03-c356-442a-9d48-5f5c27494ab6/vbnet-use-stringcollection-in-application-settings?forum=vbgeneral) for example. The duplicates and the max entries are not difficult tasks.

Comment: @dr.null so the strings are saved in the StringCollection, meaning you dont need a textfile?

Comment: Exactly, I'll post an example.

Comment: I tried to use the StringCollection but the value is not added to the Collection: Dim unused = My.Settings.MySearch.Add(PresetName.ToString)